# multiple radiobuttons selection in datagrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, radio-button

I've a datagrid with four columns (one has label and 3 columns are of radio button type) and multiple rows. I've to make sure that user must select one radio button in each row.

**Column definition for radio buttons is like this**

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Different" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" UniqueName="diff" Width="100">
  <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <telerik:RadRadioButton Name="rdbtnDiff" GroupName="DiffTariff" Width="15" Height="15"/>

     </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   </telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

If I give same **GroupName** for all radio button type columns, it allows me to select only one radio button in whole grid. and when I give different **GroupName** for all three columns, it allows me to select only one radio button in whole column. But I want it in  row.

I'm totally stuck. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately you need to ensure that groupname is unique per row so you are going to have to bind it to something, e.g. "DiffTariff + SomeIdentifier"

Comment: you can create different groups for each row.

Comment: @BenRobinson how can I do it in xaml?

Comment: @JawadZeb I know I've to do this but am not getting the point that how can I do this in xaml?

Comment: @NailaAkbar Check i have created a simple example Refactor it As your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main thing that has to be noted is, we should have a property that will remain unique across the collection. If we have such property just bind it with the groupname and radio button will work absolutely fine. It can be an **index** property or any other.

So I resolved this issue by giving a **unique group name** to each row.

[This Helped me to do this.](https://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/grouped-radiobutton-for-wpf-datagrid/)

here is sample code;

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Male">                    
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
        <DataTemplate>                            
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Index}" IsChecked="{Binding Male}" />                        
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>                
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Female">                    
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
        <DataTemplate>                            
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Index}" IsChecked="{Binding Female}" />                        
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: thanks for the correction. I edited my answer. Is it fine now?

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger is missing to update the two members: <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Index}" IsChecked="{Binding Male, , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code i have tested and working as required.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>




    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0">

        <RadioButton GroupName="row1group">Btn1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="row1group">Btn2</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="row1group">Btn3</RadioButton>

    </StackPanel>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" >


        <RadioButton GroupName="row2group">Btn1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="row2group">Btn2</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="row2group">Btn3</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: Output IS]

Comment: But I've dynamic rows count.

Comment: you can add them using java script.please add some code that i'll make changes to it.

Comment: No I've to do it without any 3rd party. And I found the solution. Thanks